# Calculate Mean of a column in R having non numeric values

Tags: r

I have a column which contain numeric as well as non-numeric values. I want to find the mean of the numeric values which i can use it to replace the non-numeric values. How can this be done in R?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? You can use `dput` for it. As you have mixed data types, I assume you're using a data frame with character or factor columns.

Comment: @nikhil -  assigning the mean to all the missing values is a terrible idea, as it will artificially reduce the variance and lead to biased estimates.

Comment: @nikhil: If you provide more context (sample data + what it represents + what you want to achieve) then we can perhaps think of a better statistical technique than straightforward substitution.

Comment: @nikhil: You really should accept an answer or respond to the comments requesting more info.  Be a good citizen!

Answer (score 9):

Say your data frame is named `df` and the column you want to "fix" is called `df$x`.  You could do the following.

You have to unfactor and then convert to numeric.  This will give you NAs for all the character strings that cannot be coalesced to numbers.

```
nums <- as.numeric(as.character(df$x))
```

As Richie Cotton pointed out, there is a "more efficient, but harder to remember" way to convert factors to numeric

```
nums <- as.numeric(levels(df$x))[as.integer(df$x)]
```

To get the mean, you use `mean()` but pass `na.rm = T`

```
m <- mean(nums, na.rm = T)
```

Assign the mean to all the NA values.

```
nums[is.na(nums)] <- m
```

You could then replace the old data, but I don't recommend it.  Instead just add a new column

```
df$new.x <- nums
```

Comment: See the FAQ on R for a better way of converting factors to numeric. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Answer (score 2):

This is a function I wrote yesterday to combat the non-numeric types. I have a data.frame with unpredictable type for each column. I want to calculate the means for numeric, and leave everything else untouched.

```
colMeans2 <- function(x) {
    # This function tries to guess column type. Since all columns come as
    # characters, it first tries to see if x == "TRUE" or "FALSE". If
    # not so, it tries to coerce vector into integer. If that doesn't 
    # work it tries to see if there's a ' \" ' in the vector (meaning a
    # column with character), it uses that as a result. Finally if nothing
    # else passes, it means the column type is numeric, and it calculates
    # the mean of that. The end.

#   browser()

    # try if logical
    if (any(levels(x) == "TRUE" | levels(x) == "FALSE")) return(NA)

    # try if integer
    try.int <- strtoi(x)
    if (all(!is.na(try.int)))  return(try.int[1])

    # try if character
    if (any(grepl("\\\"", x))) return(x[1])

    # what's left is numeric
    mean(as.numeric(as.character(x)), na.rm = TRUE)
    # a possible warning about coerced NAs probably originates in the above line
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
apply(X = your.dataframe, MARGIN = 2, FUN = colMeans2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on what your data looks like.

Does it look like this?

```
data = list(1, 2, 'new jersey')
```

Then you could

```
data.numbers = sapply(data, as.numeric)
```

and get

```
c(1, 2, NA)
```

And you can find the mean with

```
mean(data.numbers, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: You would run into problems if the vector is actually a factor, not a character (I just learned this the hard way yesterday :) ). Try: `as.numeric(as.factor(c(10,20,30)))`. @adamleerich gets it right that you have to wrap it into a `as.character` first.

Answer (score 0):

A compact conversion:

```
  vec <- c(0:10,"a","z")
  vec2 <- (as.numeric(vec))
  vec2[is.na(vec2)] <- mean(vec2[!is.na(vec2)])
```

`as.numeric` will print the warning message listed below and convert the non-numeric to `NA`.

```
Warning message:
In mean(as.numeric(vec)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```